# Is it possible to use single power supply for both op amp bias and powering the mic?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, 741-opamp

[image]

Question as in the title.
Can Vcc from identical source be used both for the op amp bias and powering the mic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C5,C6,C7 are filtering the bias supply to the microphone so it should be fine to use the same supply for both purposes.